# How do I properly use python to access system commands and make my script work?

Tags: python, linux

So the script I have is to have a larger dzen2 outputting conky on the screen when I have less than 3 workspaces open on i3 and shrink it back down when I have more than 3 workspaces open. Here's the script dzresize.py:

```
import subprocess
def main():
    #gets the number of workspaces from i3
    status = subprocess.check_output(["i3-msg", "-t", "get_workspaces"])
    #puts status in a list
    status_list = list(status)
    #sets name to 0
    name = 0
    for i in status_list:
        if i == "name":
            name +=1
    #counts the amount of name in status_list
    if len(status_list) <=3:
    #if the workspaces are less than or equal to 3, expands dzen2 with conky output
            subprocess.check_output(["conky", "-d", "-c", "~/bin/conkyrc_cli|dzen2", "-fg", "#666666", "-bg", "#333333", "-ta", "left", "-w", "725", "-x", "54", "-y", "750"])
    else:
    #if the workspaces are greater than or equal to 3 run the minimal smaller size dzen2 with conky
            subprocess.check_output(["dzconky.sh"])
main()
```

Here's the output of the scrip:

```
Conky: forked to background, pid is 18519
```

sample output (if I have 2 workspaces open) for i3-msg -t get_workspaces:

```
i3-msg -t get_workspaces
[{"num":1,"name":"1","visible":false,"focused":false,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1366,"height":749},"#output":"LVDS1","urgent":false},{"num":2,"name":"2","visible":true,"focused":true,"rect":{"x":0,"y":#0,"width":1366,"height":749},"output":"LVDS1","urgent":false}]
```

Relies on i3, dzen2 and the files ~/bin/conkyrc_cli and ~/bin/dzconky.sh. 
~/bin/conkyrc_cli:

```
# Conky configuration for Dzen2, to be piped into i3bar
##############################################
#  Settings
##############################################
background no
out_to_console yes
update_interval 1.0
total_run_times 0
use_spacer none
TEXT
^fg(\#6699cc)Processor^fg()^fg(green)${cpu cpu0}.00%^fg()^fg(white)|^fg(\#6699cc)Memory^fg()^fg(green)${memperc}.00%^fg()^fg(white)|^fg(\#6699cc)Root^fg()^fg(green)${fs_used_perc /}.00%^fg()^fg(white)|^fg(\#6699cc)Home^fg()^fg(green)${fs_used_perc /home}.00%^fg()^fg(white)|^fg(\#6699cc)Temperature^fg()^fg(green)${hwmon temp 1}'C^fg()^fg(white)|^fg(\#6699cc)Dn^fg()^fg(green)${downspeedf wlan0}KiB^fg()^fg(white)|^fg(\#6699cc)U^fg()^fg(green)${upspeedf wlan0}KiB^fg()
```

~/bin/dzconky.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec conky -d -c "$HOME/bin/conkyrc_cli" | dzen2 -fg "#666666" -bg "#333333" -ta left -w 607 -x 188 -y 750 &
exit 0
```

Edit: updated to code to reflect new changes and new output

Comment: `["i3-msg" "-t" "get_workspaces"]` Don't you need commas between these? `["i3-msg", "-t", "get_workspaces"]`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `,` in all `subprocess.call([...])`

`["i3-msg", "-t", "get_workspaces"]`

**edit:**

```
if len(status_list) <=3:
    subprocess.check_output(["dzconky_for_3_workspaces.sh"])
else:
    subprocess.check_output(["dzconky.sh"])
```

dzconky_for_3_workspaces.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
exec conky -d -c "$HOME/bin/conkyrc_cli" | dzen2 -fg "#666666" -bg "#333333" -ta left -w 725 -x 54 -y 750 &
exit 0
```

Comment: Alright I updated the question to reflect that, now I get [{"num":1,"name":"1","visible":false,"focused":false,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1366,"height":749},"output":"LVDS1","urgent":false},{"num":2,"name":"2","visible":false,"focused":false,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1366,"height":749},"output":"LVDS1","urgent":false},{"num":3,"name":"3","visible":true,"focused":true,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1366,"height":749},"output":"LVDS1","urgent":false}]
conky: invalid option -- 'f'

Comment: `conky` have problem with options - or maybe `subprocess.call` have problem with piping/redirecting `conky` to `dzen2`. You can try to put `"conky -d -c ~/bin/conkyrc_cli|dzen2 ..."` in script and call that script. And test script directly in console.

Comment: No I used the same options for conky in the dzconky.sh script and that works fine, it isn't conky having an issue.

Comment: Nope taking off the commas and quotes doesn't help there, just gives something along the lines of the initial error.

Comment: You use the same options but inside script file, not directly in `subprocess.call()`. Put `"conky -d -c ~/bin/conkyrc_cli|dzen2 ..."` in script `new-script.sh` and use `subprocess.call(['new-script.sh'])`. I think `subprocess.call()` have problem with `|` - you can even find some questions about similar problem on StackOverflow. Normally in console `|` execute subproces but `subprocess.call()` can't do this.

Comment: Alright I updated the first post to reflect the new changes and it almost works, looks like it stops right before the pipe end.

Comment: SO I read some more documentation and looked like this would work http://pastebin.com/4YFEd47t but it still doesn't do the dzen end of the pipe.
Edit: also the 'conky', '-d', 'c', method doesn't make it work any better I tried.

Comment: If script is working correctly for workspace > 3 do the same for workspace <= 3 - put `exec conky ... |dzen ... &` in file and call that file. It seems subprocess work different with code in file and with the same code called directly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: For workspaces > 3 you use `subprocess.check_output(["dzconky.sh"])`. Does it work ?

Comment: Nope changing the else statement to if len(status_list) >= 3: doesn't make it work.

Comment: You mean add the files I'm trying to call in the import line??

Comment: See code in my answer above (not in comments) to see what I'm trying to say. – `dzconky_for_3_workspaces.sh`

Comment: Ok so I tried if len(status_list) <= 3: subprocess.check_output(["dzconkyl.sh"]) and that doesn't work any better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's [sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) package. It is very nice pythonic wrapper for shell execution.
If you take a look at the [documentation](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) you will find that `sh` do probably most cases you need in a few lines.

Installation

```
pip install sh
```

From docs:

easy as:

```
from sh import curl, git, ifconfig, ls
ls()
git('fetch')
ifconfig(a=True)
```

redirections:

```
ls(_out="files.list")
ls("nonexistent", _err="error.txt")
# there is also _in for stdin
```

piping:

```
# sort this directory by biggest file
print(sort(du(glob("*"), "-sb"), "-rn"))
```

Comment: Hmm I don't see that pip package it mentions me needing to install the python-sh.

Comment: I post a link to that package on PyPI so you can grab a name from there. The name of the package is `sh`, I wrote `python-sh` as link title to PyPI package.

Comment: Ohh, I already have the regular package sh on my system by default.

Comment: from sh import i3-msg, conky, ~/bin/dzconky.sh

def main():
 status =  i3-msg (-t get_workspaces)
 if status.count("name") <= 3:
  conky ('-d -c ~/bin/conkyrc_cli|dzen2 -fg #666666 -bg #333333 -ta left -w 725 -x 54 -y 750')
 else:
  dzconky.sh
Error:  File "dzresize2.py", line 1
    from sh import i3-msg, conky, ~/bin/dzconky.sh
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Edit: sorry idk how to properly put code in comments :/

Comment: In python you cannot use names with `-`. In the sh manual there is written how to use such a names. For example first `import sh` then `i3 = sh.Command('i3-msg')`. Additionally, you have to separate command line arguments. Instead of `'-a -b -c param'` use `'-a', '-b', '-c', 'param'` as @furas said.

Comment: I'm getting lost, do I just need to redo the import line to put quotes on it?

Comment: Sorry, but I think you definitely should read `sh` documentation. There are a lot of examples how to do that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wzUbuhGx and current errors:   File "dzresize2.py", line 1
    from sh import ('i3-msg'), conky, ('~/bin/dzconky.sh')
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Why you do not read the documentation? There is almost identical example of what you need, and I posted solution three comments above.

Comment: I did and maybe I still don't get it cause I'm super rusty on python and again i3-msg Is A Command, not an argument or option it's separate from i3, running i3 doesn't do what i3-msg does (they're not the same program).

Comment: Is this better? http://pastebin.com/9Yk3bWtA Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dzresize.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sh import conky
ImportError: No module named sh

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty close. You have ImportError becouse python does not know about Command. You can get it from sh module, like `from sh import Command`.

Comment: Hmm changed it to from sh import conky, Command and I still get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dzresize.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sh import conky, Command
ImportError: No module named sh

Comment: pip install sh - you have to install the package first.

Comment: Yeah pip isn't a command for me was the issue and sh is installed, I can make sh scripts anytime...

Comment: I do not talk about `!#/bin/sh` scripts but about python library called `sh`. You have an import error which tells you that this library is not installed.